# django + ajax output errors to the form

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I use ajax to submit the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   $(document).on("submit", "#my_form", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
   $this = $(this); 
   $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    data: $this.serialize(), 
    success: function(data) 
    { console.log(data);
      if (data.result == 'success') {
       var parent=$("#my_form").parent();
       parent.html(data.success); }
       else if (data['result'] == 'error') {

      }
    }, 
    error: function(data) 
    { console.log(data); } 
  }); 
 }); 
});
```

when the form is valid, everything works fine. But I'm don’t understand how to display errors on the form if the field is entered incorrectly. They are displayed in the browser console.
[image]

I deduce the form in the template as follows:

```
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off" id="my_form">
   {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="contact-form" >
   <h1>{%trans 'Register' %}</h1>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.fio.label}} {{form.fio}}{{form.fio.help_text}}</div>
   <div class="txtb">{{form.phone.label}} {{form.phone}}{{form.phone.help_text}}{{form.errors}}</div> 
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.date_visit.label}}{{form.date_visit}}</div>
   <div class="txtb"> {{form.captcha.label}}{{form.captcha}}{{form.errors}}</div>
   <input type="submit" value="{%trans 'subbmit' %}" class="btn" id="btn">   
  </div>
</form>
```

if you need code from views.py I can add. Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// before ajax send

$("#my_form p.error").remove();
$("#my_form input").removeClass('b-error')
...
$.ajax
...
if (data.result == 'success') {
    ...
} else if (data['result'] == 'error') {
    Object.keys(data['response'].forEach(function(key) {
        $("#my_form input[name='" + key +  "'")
            .addClass('b-error')
            .after('<p class="error">' + data['response'][key] + '</p>')
    })

}
```

Comment: Why did I get an error only in the number? Is there a captcha?

Comment: I don't understand you. What number? What do you mean by last question?

Comment: when entering the wrong phone number and captcha, an error is displayed only in the number

Comment: I probably understood why. By default, django-simpel-captcha input have name captcha_1

Comment: I guess your view returns error response code and your ```error``` handler executes. Otherwise executes ```success`` executes. Try to ```console.log(arguments)``` in error handler to view all arguments.

Comment: The handler is executed, but no error is displayed in the captcha field. By default, django-simple-captcha has input name = "captcha_1". But in data ['response'] it says "captcha". This is probably why the error in this field is not displayed.

Comment: I know English bad . Therefore, I can not explain the problem well.

Comment: @ВадимШаройкин just add ```<input name="captcha" type="hidden">``` after ```{{form.captcha}}```. This little trick will solve the problem

Comment: thanks it helped. But I think it's better to go from django-simple-captcha to google recaptcha. I think there will not be such problems.